# How do I plot observations each with multiple values in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have data for each individual participant from a survey. Each individual has a vector of data for example :

```
#[a,b,c]
[1,2,5] # 1 participant
...
...
...
[1,3,4]
```

Instead of having that kind of data, I have the data column wise. Example :

```
a = [1...1] # has n values equal to participants
b = [2...3] # has n values equal to participants
c = [5...4] # has n values equal to participants
```

I need to plot this data somehow to represent it clearly as a figure, does anybody have ideas how to plot this all together? I have plotted them individually as bar plots with frequencies, but I would like them to be plotted together as a 3D plot so that all 3 dimension's values can be inferred from the data.
I have around 200 participants.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can use `zip` to change between the two formats you describe. `zip([1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4])` becomes `[(1, 1), (2, 3), (5, 4)]`.

Comment: @Josh fantastic  thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use each list as `xaxis`, `yaxis`, and `zaxis` data. This is especially useful when you know the lists are the same length, and each column represents one object. For example, `(a[0], b[0], c[0])` represent a trait of the same object. The `a-`, `b-` and `c-list` objects represent the `x-`, `-y`, and `z-axis` fields, respectively.

If you're trying to do a Scatter plot, for example:

```
import plotly as plotly
from plotly.graph_objs import *

    # stuff here, i.e. your code

    myScatter = Scatter3D(
    # some graph stuff, like your title:
    # title = 'Random_Plot_Title'
        x = a,
        y = b,
        z = c,
    # some more stuff: Here's what I tend to add
    # mode = 'markers',
    # marker = dict(
    #     color = '#DC6D37'
    # ),
    # name = 'Your_Legend_Name_Here',
    # legendgroup = 'Group_Multiple_Traces_Here',
)
```